# Averaging Offset Cells of Future Data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset

My current spreadsheet has integers that I'd like to average in every 9th cell in the K Column, starting from K10. So right now my current formula reads,

```
=AVERAGE(K9,K18,K27)
```

I'd like the EQ to consider [K36, K45, K54] even though those cells aren't filled in yet.

I believe I can use something like;

```
*pseudocode*
Find the average of K1+(K1+9)

*Attempt*
\\
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(K10,9,,,)
\\
```

I think I'm missing the complete knowledge of OFFSET, or I'm thinking maybe an AverageIF() may be in order? I've spent probably an hour on it so far

Comment: K10 + 9 <> K20.

Comment: I sort of understand what you're saying.. but without specifying whether or not using OFFSET or AverageIF is the right way to go, I'm unable to test your response. Do you mind being a little more specific, Scott? Thanks

Comment: I was not giving a formula but saying K10 + 9 is K19 not K20 as you have it in your question

Comment: Ah, thank you. Editing now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This array formula will return every 9nth cell starting with K10 and expand to include new data as it is put in:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(K:K,N(IF({1},(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,(MATCH(1E+99,K:K)-9)/9))-1)*9+10))))
```

The `-9` is the number of rows to get the starting row to row 1 `10-9=1`

The `/9` and the `*9` are the spacing

The `+10` is the starting row.

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Tried and tested to be true!

Comment: I thought it should have been =AVERAGE(INDEX(K:K,N(IF({1},(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,(MATCH(1E+99,K:K)-1)/9))-1)*9+10)))) but OP has edited the question anyway.

Comment: @TomSharpe Since Row only returns a whole number it does not matter whether it is `-1`,`-2`,...`-9`.  They all round to the correct rows.  It was easier for my brain to take it back to row 10 being 1.

Comment: Is this working? I did a simple set of alternating 1 and 2, with K10=1, K11=2, and so on up to K30. The Cells that should be averaged are K10 (value=1), K19 (value=2), and K2 (value=1) for an average of 1.33, but your formula returns 1.5

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a column as a flag, you could us the `MOD` function to check the row number like this:

`=MOD(ROW(K10)+1,9)` - this returns 0 for every 9th cell starting at K10

Then you could use the `AVERAGEIF` function to average if the `MOD` function returns 0.

If you can't add a flag, you may need to look into using an array formula like this:

`=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(ROW(K10:K30)-1,9)=0,K10:K30))`

You can activate the array formula by hitting `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. If done correctly, braces (`{}`) will be put around the formula in the formula bar.

EDIT:

**both of the following methods counts empty cells as 0

This array formula will work for column K if there is a value in every row of column K:

`=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("K10:K" & COUNTA(K:K)+10))-1,9)=0,INDIRECT("K10:K" & COUNTA(K:K)+10)))`

Or if you don't have continuous data in column K, this method gets the last filled cell.

`=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("K10:K" & MAX((K:K<>"")*(ROW(K:K)))))-1,9)=0,INDIRECT("K10:K" & MAX((K:K<>"")*(ROW(K:K))))))`

Comment: A cool way to do it! I can indeed add a column and I'll try this.